# Inner Join limit to one row

Tags: join

I have two tables t1 and t2.

t1 has field `position`

t2 has fields `start` & `stop`

My inner join is as follows:

```
select  t1.* 
from    t1 inner join t2 on t1.position >= t2.start AND t1.Pos <= t2.stop
```

Say for example:

- One of the records in `t1.position` = 8
- There are two records in t2 such that `t2.start = 1` and `t2.end = 15`; and `t2.start = 5` and `t2.end = 10`

My query will return two rows as 1 < 8 < 15 and 5 < 8 < 10.

All I want is just the first row?

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: When you say that all you want is the first row, do you always want a specific one?  Like, in your example, {start: 1, end: 15}?  Or just whichever one comes first?  The reason why this matters is that the database could return the records in your example in any order.

Comment: Which DBMS?  MySQL, SQL Server, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from t1
inner join t2 
on t1.position >= t2.start 
AND t1.Pos <= t2.stop
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either perform a distinct on the result set or use an inner query first.  If you are dealing with small data sets I would go with the distinct, otherwise use the inner query.

Distinct:

```
select distinct t1.* from t1 inner join t2 on t1.position >= t2.start AND t1.Pos <= t2.stop
```

Inner Query:

```
select t1.*
from t1
inner join
(
    select t1.position
    from t1
    inner join t2 on t1.position >= t2.start
        AND t1.position <= t2.stop
) t2 on t2.position = t1.position
```

Comment: But then when using the inner query, i dont get to see any fields from t2. How can i accomplish that?